# ggplot: change left and right axis ranges

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, axes, scatter

I need to plot two scatter plots using `ggplot`. One in which all of the values are positive ranging between (0,0.02) and another in which all of the values are negative ranging between (0,-1500). I have tried to use `sec_axis` to convey the differing scales but I have been able to produce the following.

[image]

This was produced using

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
scl = with(use_deciles, max(abs(coef_navy))/max(abs(coef_maroon)))

ggplot(use_deciles) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = decile_navy, y = coef_navy, color = 'navy')) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = decile_maroon, y = coef_maroon*scl, color = 'maroon')) +    
  labs(x = "Group", y = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('maroon', 'navy')) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~. /scl, name = "2nd axis"))
```

As you can see the `scl` provides the optimal re-scaling between the right and left axis but here is my question:

**How can I adjust the ranges of the y axes so that I can put 0 at the top of the left axis but at the bottom of the right axis?**

Given that I can only define `sec_axis` as a linear transformation of the left-axis, I'm not sure if this option can actually shift the labels. If I need to manually re-label the y-axis, that could be ok but I want to first understand how to overlay my scatter plots here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). `use_deciles` isn't defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this with @jared_mamrot data:

```
ggplot(use_deciles) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = count, y = coef_navy, color = 'navy')) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = count, y = coef_maroon*scl-1200, color = 'maroon')) +    
  labs(x = "Group", y = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('maroon', 'navy')) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.+1200)/scl, name = "2nd axis"))
```

You will get this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly,  I don't believe it is possible without changing the values. I don't think you can change the limits on the left axis without affecting the right axis, and I don't believe you can change labels for each axis independently.

A potential alternative is to use the [`facet_wrap()`](http://www.zevross.com/blog/2019/04/02/easy-multi-panel-plots-in-r-using-facet_wrap-and-facet_grid-from-ggplot2/) function to plot them on top of each other, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create example data
use_deciles <- data.frame(count = 1:10,
                          coef_maroon = c(0.005, 0.01, 0.015, 0.02, 0.03, 0.07, 0.09, 0.12, 0.15, 0.2),
                          coef_navy= c(0, -200, -400, -600, -800, -700, -900, -900, -1100, -1200))

# Original method
scl = with(use_deciles, max(abs(coef_navy))/max(abs(coef_maroon)))

ggplot(use_deciles) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = count, y = coef_navy, color = 'navy')) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = count, y = coef_maroon*scl, color = 'maroon')) +    
  labs(x = "Group", y = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('maroon', 'navy')) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~. /scl, name = "2nd axis"))
```

[image]

```r
# Facet_wrap method (on top of each other)
use_deciles %>% 
  pivot_longer(-count) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = count, y = value, colour = name)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('maroon', 'navy')) +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>