# ggplot: scale second axis with error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, axes, multiple-axes

I am attempting to graph two scatter plots with associated error bars using `ggplot2`. I would like the top of left axis to be ~0 and range down to -2000 and for the bottom of the right axis to be 0 and range up to about 0.15.

I can re-scale the axes for the points themselves following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68990984/ggplot-change-left-and-right-axis-ranges) but I am having trouble generalizing the instructions to include error bars.

Here is my current plot

[image]

Here is my code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

deciles <- data.frame(count = 1:10,
                  coef_maroon = c(0.005, 0.015, 0.015, 0.02, 0.03, 0.07, 0.09, 0.12, 0.12, 0.13),
                  ci_upper_maroon = c(0.008, 0.02, 0.025, 0.03, 0.04, 0.09, 0.11, 0.14, 0.13, 0.15),
                  ci_lower_maroon = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.005, 0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.07, 0.11, 0.11, 0.12),
                  coef_navy= c(0, -200, -400, -600, -800, -700, -900, -900, -1100, -1700),
                  ci_upper_navy = c(100, -100, -300, -500, -700, -600, -800, -700, -900, -1600),
                  ci_lower_navy = c(-100, -500, -700, -900, -850, -800, -950, -1000, -1200, -1900))

scl = with(deciles, max(abs(coef_navy))/max(abs(coef_maroon)))

ggplot(deciles) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = count, y = coef_navy, color = 'navy')) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = count, y = coef_maroon*scl-1200, color = 'maroon')) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = count, ymin = ci_lower_navy, ymax = ci_upper_navy, color = 'navy'), width = 0) +     
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = count, ymin = ci_lower_maroon*scl-1200, ymax = ci_upper_maroon*scl-1200, color = 'maroon', width = 0)) +   
  labs(x = "Group", y = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('maroon', 'navy')) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.+1200)/scl, name = "2nd axis"))
```

**My question is how can I scale my axes such that the downward trending plot (left axis) "starts" in the top left corner and the upward trending plot (right axis) starts in the bottom left?**

As you can see, there is much dead space in the top of the left axis and the right axis need not range as low as -0.05 because the smallest maroon value is just above 0.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does adjusting the scaling factor (1200 to 1900) work for you?

```r
library(tidyverse)

deciles <- data.frame(count = 1:10,
                      coef_maroon = c(0.005, 0.015, 0.015, 0.02, 0.03, 0.07, 0.09, 0.12, 0.12, 0.13),
                      ci_upper_maroon = c(0.008, 0.02, 0.025, 0.03, 0.04, 0.09, 0.11, 0.14, 0.13, 0.15),
                      ci_lower_maroon = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.005, 0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.07, 0.11, 0.11, 0.12),
                      coef_navy= c(0, -200, -400, -600, -800, -700, -900, -900, -1100, -1700),
                      ci_upper_navy = c(100, -100, -300, -500, -700, -600, -800, -700, -900, -1600),
                      ci_lower_navy = c(-100, -500, -700, -900, -850, -800, -950, -1000, -1200, -1900))

scl = with(deciles, max(abs(coef_navy))/max(abs(coef_maroon)))

ggplot(deciles) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = count, y = coef_navy, color = 'navy')) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = count, y = coef_maroon*scl-1900, color = 'maroon')) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = count, ymin = ci_lower_navy, ymax = ci_upper_navy, color = 'navy'), width = 0) +     
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = count, ymin = ci_lower_maroon*scl-1900, ymax = ci_upper_maroon*scl-1900, color = 'maroon', width = 0)) +   
  labs(x = "Group", y = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('maroon', 'navy')) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.+1900)/scl, name = "2nd axis"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Also, depending on how relevant the x-axis values are, you could consider nudging the values so they don't overlap, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

deciles <- data.frame(count = 1:10,
                      coef_maroon = c(0.005, 0.015, 0.015, 0.02, 0.03, 0.07, 0.09, 0.12, 0.12, 0.13),
                      ci_upper_maroon = c(0.008, 0.02, 0.025, 0.03, 0.04, 0.09, 0.11, 0.14, 0.13, 0.15),
                      ci_lower_maroon = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.005, 0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.07, 0.11, 0.11, 0.12),
                      coef_navy= c(0, -200, -400, -600, -800, -700, -900, -900, -1100, -1700),
                      ci_upper_navy = c(100, -100, -300, -500, -700, -600, -800, -700, -900, -1600),
                      ci_lower_navy = c(-100, -500, -700, -900, -850, -800, -950, -1000, -1200, -1900))

scl = with(deciles, max(abs(coef_navy))/max(abs(coef_maroon)))

ggplot(deciles) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = count, y = coef_navy, color = 'navy'),
             position = position_nudge(x = -0.05)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = count, y = coef_maroon*scl-1900, color = 'maroon'),
             position = position_nudge(x = 0.05)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = count, ymin = ci_lower_navy,
                    ymax = ci_upper_navy, color = 'navy', width = 0),
                position = position_nudge(x = -0.05)) +     
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = count, ymin = ci_lower_maroon*scl-1900,
                    ymax = ci_upper_maroon*scl-1900,
                    color = 'maroon', width = 0),
                position = position_nudge(x = 0.05)) +   
  labs(x = "Group", y = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('maroon', 'navy')) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.+1900)/scl, name = "2nd axis"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can further trim the 'blank space' at the top if you adjust the `expand()` option in scale_y_continuous:

```r
library(tidyverse)

deciles <- data.frame(count = 1:10,
                      coef_maroon = c(0.005, 0.015, 0.015, 0.02, 0.03, 0.07, 0.09, 0.12, 0.12, 0.13),
                      ci_upper_maroon = c(0.008, 0.02, 0.025, 0.03, 0.04, 0.09, 0.11, 0.14, 0.13, 0.15),
                      ci_lower_maroon = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.005, 0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.07, 0.11, 0.11, 0.12),
                      coef_navy= c(0, -200, -400, -600, -800, -700, -900, -900, -1100, -1700),
                      ci_upper_navy = c(100, -100, -300, -500, -700, -600, -800, -700, -900, -1600),
                      ci_lower_navy = c(-100, -500, -700, -900, -850, -800, -950, -1000, -1200, -1900))

scl = with(deciles, max(abs(coef_navy))/max(abs(coef_maroon)))

ggplot(deciles) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = count, y = coef_navy, color = 'navy'),
             position = position_nudge(x = -0.05)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = count, y = coef_maroon*scl-1900, color = 'maroon'),
             position = position_nudge(x = 0.05)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = count, ymin = ci_lower_navy,
                    ymax = ci_upper_navy, color = 'navy', width = 0),
                position = position_nudge(x = -0.05)) +     
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = count, ymin = ci_lower_maroon*scl-1900,
                    ymax = ci_upper_maroon*scl-1900,
                    color = 'maroon', width = 0),
                position = position_nudge(x = 0.05)) +   
  labs(x = "Group", y = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('maroon', 'navy')) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.+1900)/scl, name = "2nd axis"),
                     expand = c(0.01,0.01))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is all a great help! Thank you. I definitely think the 1800-2000 range is going to be the right way to go. I guess with the "real" data I'm working with the maroon line is flatter so I was hoping to adjust the scaling rather than shifting the line but this definitely satisfies the question given the provided example.